# How to fix flickering animation in css / javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to set a scale and a margin of an element to make it centered in a fluid way by using wheel event.
I want to use margins for centering as at some point I would like to set scroll position on wrapping element in fluid way as well.

As you can see in jsfiddle example I'm using css transition attribute to make it fluid.
At the same time I'm changing a scale and a margin but it looks like margin animation kicks in faster leading to moving the div side ways first. You can try it with greater zoom and do mousewheel up and down.

How to fix it so it starts and ends simultanously so the cross located in the middle of the picture doesn't move sideways during zooming in and out?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1t9pvm80/5/)

```
<html>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="el">
      +
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

```
var scale = 1;
var $wrap = $('#wrap');
var $el = $('#el');

$(function() {
  $el.on('wheel', function (e) {
    scale = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? scale * 1.5: scale / 1.5;
    e.preventDefault();

    var l = ($wrap.width() - $el.width() * scale) / 2;
    var t = ($wrap.height() - $el.height() * scale) / 2;

    $el.css({
        'transform': "scale(" + scale + ")",
      'margin-top': t + "px",
      'margin-left': l + "px",      
    });
  });
});
```

```
#wrap {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
}

#el {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  transition: 1s;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0px 0px, #666 1px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 4px 4px;
}
```

Edit: The best way to see the issue is to use mouse scroll once (one tick) and at the end of animation scroll it once again.

Edit2: So I've used Gabriele Petrioli answer and it looks good, however I still needs this info about position of the element. I came up with solution where I 'move'd margins to css transform attribute as 'translate' option and it looks working ok

I've replaced:

```
$el.css({
    'transform': "scale(" + scale + ")",
      'margin-top': t + "px",
      'margin-left': l + "px",      
    });
```

with:

```
$el.css({
    'transform': "translate(" + t + "px, " + l + "px) scale(" + scale + ")",
    });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7oykatb6/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `absolute` positioning and position it at the center from the start.

Some changes

- use `position:absolute` and `left`/`right` to position it in the center
- use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to match the grid center with the wrapper center
- set the origin to `50% 50%` as well so you do not have to account for movement
- now that you do not need the margins, you can just adjust the scale
- added a `Math.max`/`Math.min` in there just to keep the example sane for testing.

```js
var scale = 1;
var $wrap = $('#wrap');
var $el = $('#el');

$(function() {
  $el.on('wheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    scale = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? scale * 1.5 : scale / 1.5;
    scale = Math.min(Math.max(scale, 0.2) ,20);
    
    $el.css({
      'transform': `translate(-50%,-50%) scale(${Math.max(scale,0.1)})`,
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#wrap {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
}

#el {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0px 0px, #666 1px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="el">
      +
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: This works. No unexpected jumps. Ok first step achieved. Thank you.
I've mention that I want to make it scrollable (when oversized) so I've added overflow: scroll to #wrap element. I will edit my original question soon.